# Rails: active record saving time:type with unwanted format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, time

I have a table call periodo with the attribute hour. i pass my time param in this way

```
hour = Time.parse( splitLine[1] ) #where splitLine[1] is my time but in string
periodo = Periodo.new(:hour => hour.strftime("%H:%M"))
periodo.save
```

but active record save the records in this way  hour: "2000-01-01 07:00:00" , I already set the format in /config/initializers/time_formats.rb

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%H:%M"
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%H:%M"
```

and in en.yml too

```
  en:
    hello: "Hello world"
    time:
      formats:
        default: "%H:%M"
    date:
      formats:
        default: "%H:%M"
```

but my records are still saving the year and month :( what i have to do to save just the hour and minutes ???

greetings

Comment: You cannot save only hour and minutes. you can save the data as 2 fields or get the attribute as formatted time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Date formats are only valid within your application, not within the database - they are only responsible for the way time objects are displayed to your users and will not affect the way data is stored.

Unfortunately, there is no such a concept like time only in the database (at least I haven't heard about any, and trust me I did search for it as I need it in my current project)

### Simplest solution

However, in many cases it makes sense to store only the time of the event. In current project we decided to store it in format of integer `60 * hour + minutes`. This is unfortunately where we stopped in the project. :(

### One step further

You can then create a helper class (just a scaffold - more work needed like validations casting etc):

```
class SimpleTime
  attr_accessor :hour, :minute

  def initialize(hour, minute)
     @hour, @minute = hour, minute
  end

  def self.parse(integer)
    return if integer.blank? 
    new(integer / 60, integer % 60)
  end

  def to_i
    60 * @hour + @minute
  end
end
```

and then override a setter and getter:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  def time
    @time ||= SimpleTime.parse(super)
  end

  def time=(value)
    super(value.to_i)
  end
end
```

### Further fun

Now there are more things you could do. You can for example write extension `simple_time` to active_record which will automatically redefine setters and getters for a list of passed attributes. You can even wrap it in a small gem and make it real-world-proof (missing validations, string format parsers, handling `_before_type_cast` values etc).

Answer (score 1):

You have to do nothing. That is activerecord convention on time storing. So if you want to have automatically parsed time in your model from sql database you have to store it in the way AR does. But if you really want to store only hours and minutes, you should change your scheme and use just string instead of datetime in AR migration. So you can store your time like that. and in the model class you can override the attribute getter like:

```
def some_time
  Time.parse(@some_time)
end
```

Then you can get parsed time object when you call attribute. But that is a bad way actually.